# How do I port Python code that discerns which CSV header a value belongs by asking "can it be turned into a number"?

Tags: rust

The values are essentially stacked columns in a CSV that all appear in the same column. For me to discern which header a value belongs to I pretty much just say "can it be turned into a number".

The most simple example of what I am trying to do in Python in:

```py
data = ["a","1","2","3","b","4","5","6","c","7","8","9"]

class treatment:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.data = []

results = []

for d in data:
    try:
        int(d)
    except ValueError:
        results.append(treatment(name=d))
    else:
        results[-1].data.append(d)
```

This is what I have in Rust, not functional after the parsing however:

```
extern crate csv;

use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::prelude::v1::Option;
use std::process;
use std::vec::Vec;

struct Treatment {
    raw_name: String,
    channel: String,
    data: Vec<i64>,
}

impl Treatment {
    fn observe(&mut self, observation: i64) {
        &mut self.data.push(observation);
    }
}

struct Experiment {
    treatments: Vec<Treatment>,
}

impl Experiment {
    fn add_treatment(&mut self, treatment_name: &str, channel: &str) {
        &mut self.treatments.push(Treatment {
            raw_name: treatment_name.to_string(),
            channel: channel.to_string(),
            data: Vec::new(),
        });
    }

    fn get_current_experiment(&mut self) -> &Treatment {
        self.treatments.last().unwrap()
    }
}

fn deserialize_csv(file_path: String) -> csv::Reader<File> {
    csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(false)
        .from_path(file_path)
        .expect("Experienced issues reading csv file")
}

fn vectorize_string_records(mut csv_reader: csv::Reader<File>) {
    let mut experiments: Experiment = Experiment {
        treatments: Vec::new(),
    };

    for row in csv_reader.records() {
        // for these datasets we only care about data in the first cell
        let datapoint = match &row {
            Ok(T) => T.get(0),
            Err(E) => Some(""),
        }.unwrap();

        let val_as_int = datapoint.parse::<i64>();

        let current_treatment = experiments.get_current_experiment();

        // discern if value is header or datapoint
        match val_as_int {
            Ok(int_val) => &current_treatment.observe(int_val),
            Err(new_header) => &experiments.add_treatment(datapoint, &"ch=1".to_string()),
        };

        println!("{}", datapoint);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let i = deserialize_csv("/home/file.csv".to_string());
    vectorize_string_records(i);
}
```

I'm struggling with a few concepts while trying to implement this in Rust.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: @Boiethios almost always some version of mutability. You can see I can flailing trying to fix this with all my &mut in the rust code. Turns out I just needed .last_mut()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A literal port of your Python code to Rust:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Treatment {
    name: String,
    data: Vec<i32>,
}

impl Treatment {
    fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            name,
            data: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = ["a", "1", "2", "3", "b", "4", "5", "6", "c", "7", "8", "9"];
    let mut results: Vec<Treatment> = Vec::new();
    for d in &data {
        if let Ok(n) = d.parse::<i32>() {
            let last = results
                .last_mut()
                .expect("Some header must come before the values");
            last.data.push(n);
        } else {
            results.push(Treatment::new(d.to_string()))
        }
    }
    println!("results = {:#?}", results);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3c2d8abc8682bf564b2e6ccde1866b28&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: thank you very much. Theres a few things here I didn't know:

I learned about the last_mut method, I never would have tried if let (Ok)..., and I was definitely calling the 'new' method wrong the entire time. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Supposing `file.csv` is formatted like a single column containing stacked columns:

```
a
1
2
b
2
3
```

This is a snippet that reads from such a CSV file and replicates the Python logic.

It uses an iterator based approach using the `fold` combinator to accumulate treatments data:

```
extern crate csv;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Treatment {
    name: String,
    data: Vec<i32>,
}

impl Treatment {
    fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            name,
            data: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}

fn read_csv(file_path: String) -> Vec<Treatment> {
    let mut reader = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(false)
        .from_path(file_path)
        .expect("error reading csv file");

    reader
        .records()
        .fold(Vec::new(), |mut treatments: Vec<Treatment>, item| {
            match item {
                Ok(str_record) => {
                    let item = str_record.get(0).expect("missing column value");
                    match item.parse::<i32>() {
                        Ok(n) => treatments
                            .last_mut()
                            .expect("expected a header in the first row")
                            .data
                            .push(n),
                        Err(_) => treatments
                            .push(Treatment::new(item.to_string())),
                    }
               }
               Err(err) => panic!("error: {}", err),
            }
            treatments
        })
}

fn main() {
    let treatments = read_csv("./file.csv".to_string());
    println!("got: {:?}", treatments);
}
```

Comment: I think you understood wrong; I think all lines in the CSV have been catenated into a single line, and the letters (a, b, c) represent the beginning of a CSV row. At least, that's what I get from reverse-engineering the Python code.

Comment: @Matthieu M. yes - I had solved for the .get(0) aspect so I didn't reflect that part in the Python code. Thank you by the way, it turns out the largest contributor to my mutability errors was me not employing .last_mut() as these two wonderful examples show. Thank you very much!